# Centos 6.2 Minimal - DNS not resolving

Tags: linux, dns, centos

I can ping domains (ping google.co.uk) and this works OK.
However, if I do curl "http://google.co.uk" it hangs for a while and comes back with a failed message.
I also get a similar message with "yum list" stating "Failed to connect to 2a01:c0:2:4.......etc.. Network is unreachable"

I have set the resolv.conf to:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

I dont have Network Manager running, I am just using the network service.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The failing to connect is stating it is trying to connect to an ipv6 address, which means that DNS actually is working as it resolved the address to an ipv6 address and then is failing to connect to it.  It is likely that your IPV6 setup isn't operating correctly.  You should try `curl -4 http://google.co.uk` and see if that works.  If it does, then you should remove the (global) IPv6 address from your interface as it isn't working correctly.

Comment: I did think that it might be a ipv6 issue, so had already disabled it. So doesnt appear to fix the issue.